# I want to learn how to program 3D/2D applications (Games) in C#. What should I read?

Tags: c#, 3d, 2d

**I want to display my game on the screen.**
I started to write a little bit of c# code and I am now trying to get some of it displayed on the screen.

I tried to use *System.Windows.Forms / System.Drawing* but I have the feeling that it is not meant to be used in this kind of application. Everything gets updated from workerthreads all the time. I would have to use *System.Reflection* and invoke every update all the time. (methods, properties, add/remove controls). I would rather have my database thread control the information and let the UI poll the portions it needs without anything having to reflect about itself.

I want to stay within the .Net framework for portability and training reasons.
What I want my displayclasses to do is

- be in fullscreen mode
- display images for short durations as fullscreen zoom-mode (loadingscreens)
- display videos in fullscreen zoom-mode (intermission videos)
- have menues with buttons and sliders (menu, option, mission-selection)
- have a 3D world based on cubes with moving creatures and static elements while displaying a 2d overlay.

To flesh out your imagination - think about the game Dungeon Keeper 1.

**What packages do I need to know about? (please include links to the packages)

Which books can / should I read? (please include links to amazon)**

Comment: Have you looked into XNA at all?

Comment: I'd say switch to WPF instead of Windows Forms. Since you need 3D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would really suggest you to start with **Microsofts XNA** because they have done a great job to make **2D/3D development easily** accessable and you can work in an environment your are used to writing code in an *wonderful programming language* (C#).

I've made my first steps in XNA one year ago. Because I was a complete newbe to the field of computer games and especially the field of 3D programming i've been looking some time for good literature.

I found many books that belong to these topics. In the following I list the books that helped me a lot **getting started** as well as a **reference** to refer during programming.

- Aaron Reed. **Learning XNA 3.0.** *O'REILLY* 2009 (ISBN: 978-0-596-52195-0)
- Riemer Grootjans. **XNA 3.0 Game Programming Recipes - Problem-Solution Approach.** *aPress* 2009 (ISBN: 978-1-4302-1855-5)

Rimer Grootjans has a very usefull website with topic XNA Game Development (At least he had it one year ago ;)) - I used his site exhaustively for problem solving and learing XNA concepts.

- Michael C. Neel. **XNA 3D Primer.** *WILEY* (WROX BLOX)
- Alexandre Santos Lobao et. al. **Beginning XNA 3.0 Game Programming - From Novice to Professional.** *aPress* 2009 (ISBN: 978-1-4302-1817-3)
- Sean James. **3D Graphics with XNA Game Studio 4.0.** *PACKT* 2010 (ISBN: 978-1-849690-04-1)
- Rob Miles. **Introduction to Programming Through Game Developmnt Using Miscrosoft XNA Game Studio.** *Microsoft Press* 2010

Take a look in these books they cover introductions as well as further concepts for both XNA Game Development in particular and 3D programming in general.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I am working myself throug a tutorial right now. XNA is really awsome.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C#, you should look into [XNA Game Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23714). This supports all aspects of game development, including 2D, 3D, input devices and audio.

It comes with lots of samples and would be a really good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Use a package that is actually made for programming games in C# - [XNA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb200104.aspx). The [App Hub](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/education/gamedevelopment) has a bunch of tutorials to get you started. This [link](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/tutorial/2dgame/getting_started) is for a 2D game.

For a book, I find [Learning XNA 4.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449394620) a good resource for anyone learning game development using XNA. Also, there's this other book - [XNA 4.0 Game Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849690669). I haven't read it but the reviews say that it's beginner-friendly. So you may want to give that a try as well.